# What reporting tools can I use for an XML datasource?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-applications, reporting

I'm looking for a reporting tool that I can use with an XML datasource. The XML files would be small, approximately 50-60K but may be as large as 200K. The goal of our project is to generate reports based on data submitted in the XML file.

I understand I could simply use XSLT style sheets and output HTML but I prefer PDF, XPS, XLS, or DOC output and want better formatting control. Any suggestions?

Most likely we will not have SQL Server on the machine so Sql Server reporting is probably not going to be an option. Please correct me if I'm wrong. . .

Answer (score 1):

Sql server reporting services (sSRS)

Answer (score 1):

BIRT can handle XML input provided you have an ODA source for it (you may need to write it yourself depending on the complexity of your XML).

We've been using BIRT with database sources for quite a while and we're only just morphing our code to handle XML input, as a way of tacking our excellent code onto other products in a relatively painless way.

[This page](http://www.birt-exchange.org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/70-birt-xml-data-source/#description) was our jumping-off point and is quite helpful.